# What's different about the new TIE fighters?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

As a follow up to [the question about hyperdrives on TIE fighters](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111988/do-first-order-ties-have-hyperdrives), what is different about the new First Order standard type TIE fighters vs. Galactic Empire ones?

Here is the old version the Empire used:
[image: Old TIE]

Besides aesthetics, what changes has the TIE fighter undergone?

Comment: @DVK I can't seem to find the correct picture then, of a non red hulled new version.

Comment: In the movie they got a back co pilot like the Arc 170

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111852/whats-different-about-the-new-x-wing-fighters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **main** difference worth noting is that new TIEs (Official name: "TIE/fo space superiority fighter") **got deflector shields**.

Source: *Star Wars: The Force Awakens: Incredible Cross-Sections*

Also:

> While visibly similar to older TIE/lns<sup>[1]</sup>, these latest models boast improved solar cells and higher-capacity converters, the products of Imperial research conducted for the TIE Advanced program.

Also

> - Thrusters rotated 90% from old TIE models for increased maneuvrability

<sub>[1] - your picture in the question is looking so different from old TIE for a reason - it's NOT a TIE fighter. It's a very upgraded TIE/sf Special Forces model, distinguished by red hull (because cool?)</sub>

Comment: I think there are some other difference not **officially** noted in canon explicitly as well, such as having subspace communication antenna that IIRC TIE/ln lacked)

Comment: Not only that.....those tie's are 2 seated and have multiple weapon systems instead of just blasters AND a hyperdrive BUT I read somewhere that these are just special forces ties that have those abilities

Comment: @Thomas - no they are not. You're confusing TIE/fo and TIE/sf. I answered that in a linked question in detail :)

Comment: yepp you are right I'm confusing them ti seems. Just saw the picture on that linked question and the accepted answer there. Right above the cockpit the one that was stolen in the beginning did have a weapon mount the one in the picture in the other answer does NOT have that weapon mount so clearly 2 versions of ties