# What specifically made it so that a TIE fighter wouldn't be out near Alderaan by itself?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship, a-new-hope

In "A New Hope", when the Falcon arrives at the ruins of Alderaan, they encounter a TIE fighter. Someone remarks that such a small ship wouldn't be out that far by itself. However, in "The Empire Strikes Back" we see that Luke's X-Wing, arguably a comparable craft as they served the same purpose, was able to travel to Dagobah on its own. What was it that the characters meant about the TIE fighter, and what made it too small to be out as far as it was?

Comment: Not an expert, so posting as a guess, but ISTR TIE fighters don't have hyperdrives.

Comment: This answer https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111991/101407 provides a source that even First Order TIE fighters still lack hyperdrives.

Comment: One of the major selling points of the X-Wing was having a Hyperdrive, despite being a small fighter.

Comment: X-Wings serve the purpose of bringing freedom to the Galaxy! TIE fighters serve the purpose of X-Wing target practice.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - X-Wings are used by anti-government terrorists for their nefarious attacks on legitimate Imperial installations.

Comment: One other difference is an X-Wing is capable of folding its wings together and landing on a planet.  I feel like a TIE fighter's wings would collapse under their own weight on a planet's surface.  We occasionally see them parked, but only inside larger spaceships, where there's presumably some sort of hand-wavy gravity control...

Comment: @OrganicMarble What is ISTR? I looked up ISTR TIE fighter in Google and couldn't find anything relevant. In fact this question was one of the top results because of your comment.

Comment: @CaveJohnson Do you need any more volunteers for testing at this time? I'm not an astronaut or Olympian,but I would like to try that blue gel though. Getting back to your question, ISTR is an acronym for **I** **S**eem **T**o **R**ecall.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I don't know about Canon, but in Legends TIEs are depicted landing on their wings on various outdoor surfaces without any apparent technological help. Their wings are thin but not *that* thin.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your comparison to an X-Wing is not actually a great comparison. That’s like comparing a Citroën Méhari to a Hummer H1. They’re both utility vehicles, and they have a handful of other similarities, but they are drastically different vehicles. Similarly, the Incom T-65B X-Wing and the Sienar Fleet Systems TIE/ln are both general-purpose star-fighters, but they are still drastically different.

The key differences that are relevant for this question¹ are that:

- The TIE/ln has no hyperdrive, while the T-65B X-Wing has a class 1 hyperdrive (which meant that even in hyperspace, it was actually faster than most capital ships).
- The TIE/ln only has sufficient room for two days of provisions, while the T-65B X-Wing has sufficient room for a full week of provisions.

Taken all together, this means that the *absolute furthest* that a TIE/ln fighter could be from it’s operational base unless it’s traveling to a different base that can resupply it is one day of sub-light travel. With a stated maximum acceleration of 4100G, no stated max speed outside of atmosphere, and ignoring relativistic effects, that translates to a distance of roughly 37.53 terameters (billion kilometers). This is roughly 1.5 times the distance from Earth to Voyager 1, still nowhere near far enough to get to another star system in a vast majority of cases (despite how obscenely fast it would be going).

That assumes though that all the TIE/ln pilot does is accelerate in a straight line for half a day, decelerate to a stop for half a day, turn around, and do the exact same thing again. Of course, that’s unrealistic for actual operations, with the likely combat effective range (how far it could be away from base and still be useful in a dogfight under the assumption it would have to return to base eventually) probably being at most around 1/3 of that, or maybe 1/2 at best (there is no canonical data I can find about this or any of the things I would need to infer this, it’s just a rough guess based on my limited knowledge of real-life fighter aircraft).

What that means is that from a practical perspective, if you see a TIE/ln fighter patrolling or scouting (which is what was seen in Episode IV), it’s a near certainty that there is either an Imperial military base *or* a large Imperial capital ship in the same star system as you.

---

1: For those who are interested, the other major differences are that the TIE/ln lacks shields, that it has only rudimentary life support (that’s why the pilots always wear those bulky full-body suits), and that it costs roughly 2/5 what a T-65B X-Wing does. The cost difference is why the Empire had them designed, the intent was to mass produce them and then rely on quantity of pilots instead of quality.

Comment: I think the fundamental underlying philosophy difference here was that the Empire was perfectly happy with using [human wave tactics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_wave_attack), both on the ground and in space (with their small 1-man craft). They presumably had the recruiting base on a galactic level to support that, and didn't mind a few grunt losses if it allowed them to show up to trouble spots with what looked like overwhelming force.

Comment: @T.E.D. Their ground troops were clones.

Comment: @Davislor Actually, most weren’t. After Palpatine’s successful coup, cloning operations on Kamino were shut down (along with all other cloning operations throughout the galaxy) as they were considered a major security risk (the Imperial government was concerned about a rebellion pulling the same thing the Republic did at the start of the Clone Wars), and while a majority of the clone troopers from the Republic military did become stormtroopers, new recruits were almost exclusively not clones.

Comment: “ignoring relativistic effects” when accelerating to 5.8 times the speed of light — does this still qualify as sub-light travel? According to https://space.stackexchange.com/a/960/39231, it could reach Voyager 1 faster than actual light ;–)

Comment: @Davislor - And of course New Hope was a generation after the end of the Clone Wars, and clones age twice as fast as normal humans. So by the time of the iconic X-wing vs. Tie battles from the original trilogy, all the clones would have been retirees. Some of them show up in a Rebels episode as old men with white beards, about 4 years before Yavin (destruction of the first Death Star).

Comment: @wrtlprnft True, but the fact that it’s such a (comparatively) short range even ignoring relativity reinforces that the TIE/ln is an in-system vessel only. That, and there seriously is no canonical top speed for these things outside of a planetary atmosphere, so a ‘proper’ answer would involve an arbitrary decision on a max speed regardless.

Comment: @wrtlprnft Well, we are talking about the Star Wars-universe, where even the "piece of junk"-Millenium Falcon can make ".5 past light speed"...

Comment: An acceleration of 4100G? For how many nanoseconds is it sustainable by a human being?

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica More likely femtoseconds, not nanoseconds. But then, Star Wars isn’t hard sci-fi (it’s not even sci-fi at all, it’s fantasy that happens to mostly take place in a space-opera-like setting), and there are much more egregious violations of real world physics than this.

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica - There's some form of artificial gravity on Star Wars ships, so maybe they can create an artificial gravity field of ~4100G in the opposite direction to neutralize the G-force from acceleration. [According to a footnote on the infobox on the wookieepedia page](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/TIE/ln_space_superiority_starfighter) the 4,100 G figure is found in the canon [*TIE Fighter Owners' Workshop Manual*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/TIE_Fighter_Owners%27_Workshop_Manual), anyone have that book to see if it says anything about the G-force?

Comment: @wrtlprnft - If non-hyperspace travel in Star Wars obeys relativity, we could use the [relativistic rocket equations](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/Rocket/rocket.html) to see how far it could get accelerating at 4100G for 1 day. Using units of years for time and light-years for distance, c=1 ly/y and 4100G=4232 ly/y^2 and 1 day = 0.00274 y, so plugging in those values for c, a and t into the equation for d gives 0.00251 light years, or about 23.7 billion km. This is just slightly under the distance to Voyager 1, about 23.8 billion km.

Comment: @Hypnosifl If we assume that the distance is limited by life support, the passing of time inside the fighter is relevant. According to the page you linked (CTRL-F “Nearest star”, the equation above the table), it would take only 10.6 hours to travel and come to a stop at Voyager 1, accelerating at 41000 m/s². In 24 hours, it could travel 8×10^14 m, or 33.6 earth-voyager distances.

Comment: @wrtlprnft Good point, if relativity still held, 1 day of food for those on board the ship would work out to a longer period for external observers due to time dilation. But I get a much larger distance--in those equations T stands for onboard time, so if we have T=1 day=0.00274 y, c=1 ly/y and a=4232 ly/y^2, then according to the equation for d as a function of T, we should have d = (1/4232)*(cosh(4232*0.00274) - 1) and plugging that in [here](https://keisan.casio.com/calculator) gives a distance of 12.8 light-years. Maybe it can't do 4100G for such a sustained time though.

Comment: Ah but maybe you were calculating what happens if it accelerates for half a day (0.00137 y) and then decelerates for the second half--in that case the equation says that in half a day it travels 0.0387 ly, and deceleration is symmetrical so another 0.0387 ly, for a total of 0.0774 ly, or 7.3 * 10^14 m, close to what you had (one of us may just have rounded the numbers more).

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica - Adding to my earlier comment about using artificial gravity to compensate for G-forces, wookieepedia has an [article](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Acceleration_compensator) about "acceleration compensators" or "inertial compensators" which prevent pilots from "from being killed by excessive g-forces". I couldn't find anything saying specifically that TIE Fighters have them, but the canon novel *Tarkin* has him flying a V-wing that is a similarly stripped-down craft, without life-support or hyperdrive, and it is said to have an inertial compensator.

Comment: Just did another search and found a [short story](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Amara_Kel%27s_Rules_for_TIE_Pilot_Survival_(Probably)) from a 2020 anthology of Empire Strikes Back related stories, the "weapons and technology" section of the wookieepedia article mentions the story does have inertial compensators. I downloaded a copy of the ebook, there's a flashback scene of a past battle where the main character was flying a TIE Fighter, it says she "screamed through an arc so tight that the force coming past the inertial compensator was enough to squeeze my eyeballs".

Comment: @Hypnosifl I like the idea of inertial compensators. As implausible as such a thing seems to be, at least it means they realized how crazy 4100G is, and thought of how to deal with it. I still think it would have been easier to say that the maximum acceleration is around 10G... But I guess it's too late for that.

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica 4100G is actually kind of crazy in-universe too TBH. Most other fighters can only manage something around 3000G tops (X-Wings are one of the few other exceptions, topping out around 3700G, almost all other fighters that we have numbers for are in the 2500-3000G range), and many transports are an order of magnitude below that. A lot of the numbers are kind of crazy IRL though, such as ships with power plants capable of instantaneous output measured in _yottawatts_ (only a few orders of magnitude less than our sun).

Answer (score 28):

The film's [official novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(novel)) gives us a little more insight. Han sees the TIE and guesses (rightly) that this is the short-range version, one known to not have a hyperdrive. Kenobi then scans the ship and confirms this.

> Chewbacca suddenly gave an angry bark. A huge flower of destruction blossomed outside the port, battering the freighter violently. A tiny, double-winged ball raced past the cockpit port.
>
> “It followed us!” Luke shouted.
>
> “From Tatooine? It couldn’t have,” objected a disbelieving Solo. “Not
> in hyperspace.”
>
> Kenobi was studying the configuration the tracking screen displayed.
> “You’re quite right, Han. **It’s the short-range TIE fighter.”**
>
> <sub><sup>Star Wars: A New Hope by George Lucas</sup></sub>

Comment: It is slightly ambiguous - Kenobi is either describing a characteristic of all tie fighters that they're short-range, or he's saying its the kind of tie fighter that is short-range compared to long range tie fighters.  Instinctively we know its the former, because in battle time is short and words are precious.  Substitute something like a colour and "red tie fighter" is different to "purple tie fighter".

Comment: @Criggie - We know that TIEs come in a variety of flavours including ones that have a hyperdrive as standard

Comment: @valorum To be fair, the term "TIE" regarding starfighters is similar to "Chevvy" regarding cards. It's more a group of vehicles than one specific model.

Comment: As an example, at the end of the movie, Darth Vader is flying a TIE fighter with a hyperdrive.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson - His is a rare model with a low grade hyperdrive

Comment: @Valorum It doesn't matter, it remains a TIE fighter, a unique one, but one nonetheless.

Comment: Pedantic but the credit for the Novelisation belongs to Alan Dean Foster - not George.

Comment: @Secretsquirrel - The pedant in me would point out that the [book cover clearly states that Lucas is the author](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/599090.Star_Wars) and while it's common knowledge that Alan Dean Foster was the ghost-writer, I don't believe that's been officially acknowledged